# Does ZFC without Foundation prove that given any proper class A, every set can be injected into A ?

Tags: set-theory

I have a proof in ZFC, using AC and the axiom of foundation, that given any proper class A, every set can be injected into A. I wonder if we could have a proof of this that does not use Foundation.
Gérard  Lang

Comment: I think that you have another account, no? You can ask on the meta site to have them merged.

Comment: Interesting. Would it be correct to infer that the overall strategy is to prove, presumably by transfinite induction, that it is possible to inject any $V_\alpha$?

Comment: Upvote for a compelling statement that requires Replacement.

Comment: Adam, in ZFC (proper!) it's easy to prove. Let $x$ be a set, well order it. Since $A$ is a proper class for every $\alpha$ there is $\beta>\alpha$ such that $V_\beta\cap A$ has *more* elements than $V_\alpha\cap A$. Let $\alpha_i$, $i<|x|$ be a strictly increasing sequence of the least ordinals where information on $A$ is added. For every $i<|x|$ map $x_i\in x$ to some element in $V_{\alpha_i}\cap A\setminus A\cap\bigcup_{j<i}V_{\alpha_j}$.

Comment: Also, it should be remarked that the use of choice is also essential. It is consistent that there is a proper class without a countably infinite subset.

Comment: In a funny way this is different from what I was expecting. Here it seems that the use of Foundation is to guarantee that $A$ is contained in  the cumulative hierarchy, rather than that $x$ is.
Might there be  a way to put  actual meat  on this  observation,  in some context or another, say something about Choice  vs Global Choice in the absence of Foundation?

Comment: Adam, I did use this fact. But I used a slightly weaker fact, if $WF$ is the inner model of well-founded sets, then every proper class $A$ intersects $WF$ in a proper class as well. That is, there is only a set of ill-founded sets. Global choice would imply that the entire universe is equipotent with the ordinals, so it's gonna be even easier to prove this result, even without foundations (and without the aforementioned assumption). Simply well order the universe then map the part of $x$ into some initial segment of $A$.

Comment: I don't see that you are using that $x$ is well-founded, just that it is bijective  to an ordinal. Am I missing  something?  I was  also starting to wonder about the situation when Foundation+Choice is replaced by "every set is equinumerous to a well-founded set", but above you point to a less exotic failure already.

Comment: Adam, I misread your comment and thought that you expected $A$ to be contained in the cumulative hierarchy. But do note that the models which I refer to in my answer are models where the atoms do not form a set. I am fairly certain that if there is a set of atoms then these principles hold (we assume choice, so every set is equinumerous to an ordinal).

Comment: I am sure I must be missing something very basic (and that I'll eventually be embarrassed to have asked this) but:  How can you possibly prove anything about proper classes *in ZFC* when ZFC doesn't even let you *talk* about proper classes?

Comment: Steven, this is sort of a meta-theorem. Proper classes in ZFC are syntactical constructs, definable collections. We can prove the following meta theorem: *Let $\varphi(x)$ be a formula, such that for all $x$ there exists $u\notin x$, and $\varphi(u)$ holds. Then there exists $y$ such that $u\in y\to\varphi(u)$ and a bijection between $x$ and $y$.*

Comment: In principle there are finer points somewhat suppressed in ZFC. For example, some arguments might use classes in a way that could be  formalized in NBG, without any reference  to  structure due to definability, whereas other arguments might well require proofs by induction on quantifier complexity. Maybe some expert could weigh in about this, at least whether it is worth formulating as its  own quesstion.

Comment: E.g. "The Kunen inconsistency result, the assertion that there is no nontrivial elementary embedding j:V→V, becomes trivial when one treats all classes as definable. One can easily rule out all such definable j, if one only cares to consider the case in which j is first-order definable with parameters, and one needs neither the axiom of choice nor any infinite combinatorics to do it."  from Joel David Hamkins's  answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/71765/are-proper-classes-objects/71773#71773.

On the other hand, first-order definability is surely crucial  for  Reflection Principles.

Comment: I have merged your accounts, but it might be good to register this one.

Comment: Asaf Karaglia:  Thanks for clarifying this.  Presumably the last sentence of your comment should have started with the quantifier "For all x".  

Comment: Dear Scott Carnahan,
Let me thank you very much for having merged my two counts.
I will try to register as you ask me to do.
GL

Comment: Steven, I'm not 100% sure what you mean by that. The point is that we first quantify over the formula, then over the variables. This is why this is a meta-theorem rather than a theorem.

Comment: Asaf:  Yes, I understand that you are quantifying over formulas and that's why this is a metatheorem.  You have quantified over all formulas $\phi$ that do not define sets.  Then you say that for all such $\phi$, "there exists a $y$ such that $u\in y\rightarrow \phi(u)$ and a bijection between $x$ and $y$."  In the quoted phrase, $x$ appears to be a free variable.  To make sense of it, it seems to me that I have to prepend the quantifier "for all $x$".  No?

Comment: Steven, but $x$ is quantified. I should have used a different variable for $\varphi$ I suppose, but I said that *...for all $x$ there exists $u\notin x$ such that $\varphi(u)$ holds*, that is to say there is no set which is exactly all the objects satisfying $\varphi$. If that happens, then there is $y$ such that $y=\{u\in y\mid\varphi(u)\}$ and $|x|=|y|$.

Comment: Asaf: Perhaps I'm being dense, but this still seems wrong to me. For each fixed ϕ, we have a sentence of the form "A(ϕ) implies B(ϕ)". For this to make sense, both A(ϕ) and B(ϕ) must be sentences. Now A(ϕ) is the perfectly good sentence "For all x, there exists u $\notin$ x such that ϕ(u)".  But B(ϕ) is the phrase "There exists y such that y=$\{u\in y|\phi(u)\}$ and |x|=|y|". It still looks to me like x appears as an unbound variable in the alleged sentence B(ϕ), and that to turn B(ϕ) into a legitimate sentence, I must quantify over x.

Comment: Steven, when you parse my sentence this way then indeed the quantifier on $x$ is outside the implication. And indeed this was the intended meaning, $A(\varphi,x)$ is "There exists $u\notin x$ ..." and $B(\varphi,x)$ was "There exists $y$ such that ..." and the whole statement was actually $\forall x(A(\varphi,x)\rightarrow B(\varphi,x))$, if you grant me the meta-parameter $\varphi$.

Comment: Asaf:  But with your intended reading, it seems that your metatheorem is false.  Let's take $\phi(x)$ to mean "$x$ is empty" and let $P$ be the set of prime numbers.  Then your $A(\phi,P)$ says (truly) that there exists an empty set that is not a prime number.  And $B(\phi,P)$ says (falsely) that there is a countably infinite set all of whose members are empty.  So it is false that $A(\phi,P)\rightarrow B(\phi,P)$ and consequently false that "For all $x$, $A(\phi,x)\rightarrow B(\phi,x)$".  On the other hand, it *is* true that "(For all $x$, $A(\phi,x)$)"\rightarrow "(For all $x$, $B(\phi,x)$"

Comment: Steven, I haven't said that it is true for *any* class. I said that this is how one can formulate the meta-theorem that every set injects into every *any proper class*. Now I'm confused and I feel I may have misquantified in my previous comment. Let me think about it and get back to you with the correct statement...

Comment: Okay, here is the correct statement of what I had meant. Suppose that $\varphi(u)$ is a formula then **if for every set $x$ there exists $u$ such that $\varphi(u)$ and $u\notin x$** then **for every $x$ there exists $y$ such that $y=\{u\in y\mid \varphi(u)\}$ and $|x|=|y|$**. So you were right about the quantifiers on the $x$ variable, but now it seems correctly phrased. I hope we can move on to a more meaningful discussion from this point onwards. :-)

Comment: Asaf:  yes, now I think we are in total agreement.  Thanks for sticking this out to the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. This principle is known as **The Injection Principle**

See in Jech **Axiom of Choice**, Chapter 9, Problems 3 and 4 both give us a models of ZF+Atoms (so foundation fails) *with choice* in which the injection principle fails.

Comment: Adam, neither of the editions. I don't know why I wrote "Set Theory". I was literally holding the book in my hand when I typed that answer. Strange... :-) Thanks!!

Comment: 

Thanks, Asaf. But these are in Jech's **The Axiom of Choice** rather than **Set Theory**

Comment: Adam, that's what I edited. Yes.

Comment: Dear Asaf, thank you very much, I am happy to credit you with for this answer. But, in fact, I was thinking to ZFC set theory without atoms; does the result in Jech transfer without atoms ?
It is perfectly true that I have two distinct counts in Mathoverflow for reasons that I cannot understand. My older one, with more than 500 points recognized my true e-mail beginning with"gerard_lang@". But, now it is impossible for me to connect on this count, and I have another newer one, with 1OO points, that wants only to recognize "gerard-lang@ ", that is not my correct electronic adress ! Gérard Lang

Comment: Dear Gerard, If you have a proper class of sets of the form $\lbrace x\rbrace = x$ then I believe that you can treat them as atoms and repeat all the constructions and have this.

Comment: My sympathies, Gerard. I myself once lost 120 points overnight - upvotes to my most popular question mathoverflow.net/questions/120598/…due to my own overzealous editing which inadvertently rendered it community wiki. I'll admit to having been more annoyed than I might have expected :( And yes, as Asaf points out, you can always simulate atoms by Quine atoms